# Bootstrap-Table error al cargar la tabla con JSON en JavaScript y PHP

Tags: ajax, json, bootstrap-table

Necesito su ayuda con lo siguiente. Tengo una Bootstrap-Table versión 3 y al querer utilizar AJAX en JavaScript no puedo cargar los datos correctamenten.
Si al Body de la Tabla lo cargo con un código de PHP, funciona bien, pero no quiero colocar el código PHP dentro del HTML por seguridad.

Así se ve el listado que quiero ver. La primer fila supuestamente dice que no encuentra registros. Nose por qué ocurre esto porque debajo me carga todo sin problemas (igualmente no muestra la paginación)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, comparto el código HTML:

```
<table id="tbllistado" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
<thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                                                <th data-field="idusuario">ID</th>
                                                <th data-field="nombre" data-editable="true">Nombre</th>
                                                <th data-field="tipo_documento" data-editable="true">Documento</th>
                                                <th data-field="num_documento" data-editable="true">Nro Documento</th>
                                                <th data-field="telefono" data-editable="true">Teléfono</th>
                                                <th data-field="email" data-editable="true">Email</th>
                                                
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="tbllistadobody">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>



**JAVASCRIPT:**
<script>
init();

//funcion que se ejecuta al inicio
function init(){
   listar5();
}

function listar5(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../../modelos/testing.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {

          console.log(data);

            data.forEach( ( elemento ) => {
                const row = `<tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>${elemento.idusuario}</td>
                <td>${elemento.nombre}</td>
                <td>${elemento.tipo_documento}</td>
                <td>${elemento.num_documento}</td>
                <td>${elemento.telefono}</td>
                <td>${elemento.email}</td>
                </tr>`;
                $('#tbllistadobody').append( row );
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>

**PHP (testing.php):**
<?php 
//incluir la conexion de base de datos
require "../config/Conexion.php";

    $sql="SELECT idusuario, nombre, tipo_documento, num_documento, telefono, email FROM usuarios";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); //Obtiene consulta SQL
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Convierte en ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($datos); //Convierte en JSON

 ?>
```

El archivo JSON lo trae OK porque lo puedo ver en la consola.

Si no utilizo la Bootstrap-Table lo puedo ver sin problemas con las tablas HTML.

Qué podrá ser que los datos no se ven bien?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné colocando el JSON directamente sobre la tabla de Bootstrap, con el evento "load". Dejo la respuesta:

```
function listar5() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../../modelos/testing.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      
      $('#tbllistado').bootstrapTable('load', data); 

    }
  });
}
```

Gracias de todos modos!